# Code First table per hierarchy mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an `Organisation` entity which represents businesses that can be a *supplier*, a *customer* or *both*.

The entity looks like this:

```
public abstract class Organisation
{
    public Organisation()
    {
        IsCustomer = false;
        IsSupplier = false;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSupplier { get; set; }
    public bool IsCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

I have created sub-classes of organisation called `Customer` and `Supplier` as this will make things easier when working with `Organisations` in other parts of my domain (E.G. Only an `Organisation` that is a `Supplier` can be associated with a purchase order).

I have created two classes that derive from the `Organisation` class.

```
public class Supplier : Organisation
{
}

public class Customer : Organisation
{
}
```

Next I want to tell Entity Framework how to map these classes to the table. All information will be stored in a single table called 'Organisations' so I am trying to use a TPH (table-per-hierarchy) mapping.

Here is how I want my mapping to work:

- If I query `Organisations`, I want Entity Framework to return all organisations regardless of the values in the `IsCustomer` and `IsSupplier` properties.
- If I query `Suppliers`, I want Entity Framework to return all organisations where `IsSupplier = true`.
- If I query `Customers`, I want Entity Framework to return all organisations where `IsCustomer = true`.

It is valid for an organisation to be both a customer and a supplier so I would expect some organisations to be included in both `Customer` and `Supplier` queries.

Here is the configuration class I have defined:

```
class OrganisationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Organisation>
{
    internal OrganisationConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Organisations");
        HasKey(o => o.Id);

        Map<Customer>(m =>
            {
                m.Requires("IsCustomer").HasValue(true);
            });

        Map<Supplier>(m =>
            {
                m.Requires("IsSupplier").HasValue(true);
            });
    }
}
```

This results in a `DataException` being thrown with the following message:

> error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 59:Condition
>   member 'Organisation.IsSupplier' with a condition other than
>   'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on
>   Organisation.IsSupplier or remove it from the mapping.

I'm not sure how to fix this error, or even if what I want to do is possible as all examples I have seen have a single discriminator column. I'm not sure I would be able to achieve the result I want with a single discriminator though as I would need to distinguish between organisations that are both customers and suppliers.

**Update:**

After some research it seem the error is a result of me having the `IsSupplier` and `IsCustomer` properties defined in my `Organisation` class. If I remove these properties then my database is built properly and my mapping works (Entity Framework creates **separate** discriminators in my table).

I have tested this with 3 separate queries (1 to select `Organisations`, 1 to select `Customers` and 1 to select `Suppliers`) and this seems to get me the correct results so this has got me about 90% of the way toward my solution.

The problem I have now is that I require a way to select a `Customer` from the database and also set is as a supplier (as I have no property to set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Can't try it right now but I think only 1 discriminator column is allowed.</strike>

```
public abstract class Organisation
{
    ...
    //public bool IsSupplier { get; set; }
    //public bool IsCustomer { get; set; }
    public int SubType { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
   Map<Customer>(m =>
        {
            m.Requires("SubType").HasValue<int>(1);
        });

   Map<Supplier>(m =>
        {
            m.Requires("SubType").HasValue<int>(2);
        });
```

You should of course define an enum to replace the int.

---

You've already figured that out, but

> It is valid for an organisation to be both a customer and a supplier
>   ....
>   as I would need to distinguish between organisations that are both customers and suppliers.

That simply goes against the basic OOP principles here. An instance can not be of 2 derived types, that's not supported in C#.

If you want to implement this you need an entirely different design.

---

> that I require a way to select a Customer from the database and also set is as a customer (as I have no property to set).

You can select either a Customer or a Supplier with the `OfType<>` method:

```
 IEnumerable<Customer> allCustomers = myContext.Organisations.OfType<Customer>();
```

and you can simply add a customer to the common entityset:

```
var c = new Customer(....);
myContext.Organisations.Add(c);
```

In general you don't use the Discriminator properties in queries.

Comment: Thanks. I have added an update to my question which shows that Entity Framework works fine with separate discriminators if I remove the properties. I take on board what you are saying about the OOP design principles but I am actually using a different design right now which basically involves checking the properties to ensure the right 'type' of organisation is being used but this feels like a hack to me which is why I was looking at this method which would give me type safety.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my update; I want to be able to convert a customer to a supplier and vice versa. I think you're right that what I want can't be done with the design I have so I am investigating some other ideas at the moment.

Comment: Your comments about the OOP principles are right. While it would be convenient for Entity Framework to work the way I want, it doesn't really make sense and I think I was trying to be too clever. After some experimentation I can get the effect I want with 3 classes that are not related via inheritance using navigation properties.